# Keras image similarity model trouble with labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, training-data

I am working on a deep image similarity model and I would like to get some help on it.

I keep getting this error and don't know what to exactly do with it or how to fix it.

```
Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 100 input samples and 3 target samples.
```

I have the images broken up into three files which I then read in. I then have three arrays (anchor, positive, and negative). The label I have will all be the same y =[1,1,0] i.e. [a,p,n]
Is this the right approach for this?

I am following this blog/code  https://medium.com/@akarshzingade/image-similarity-using-deep-ranking-c1bd83855978

The model and loss function are the same, the only difference I change is what data I load and how to load it and how I train the model.

```
# Alist of images for anchor similar and negative
# Read in all the image paths
anchor = np.load("list/anchor_list.npy")
pos = np.load("list/positvie_list.npy")
neg = np.load("list/negative_list.npy")

def load_img(path):
    img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(224, 224))
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    img = np.array(img)
    return img

a = []
p = []
n = []
# Read in sampple of the images
for i in range(0, 100):
    a.append(load_img(os.path.join(data_dir, anchor[i])))
    p.append(load_img(os.path.join(data_dir, pos[i])))
    n.append(load_img(os.path.join(data_dir, neg[i])))

a = np.array(a)
p = np.array(p)
n = np.array(n)
y = [1, 1, 0]

deep_rank_model.fit([a, p, n], y,
                batch_size=batch_size,
                epochs=10,
                verbose = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the error, the input array [a,p,n] is of size(100x3) but your output array y is of size (1x3). So the model is not able to pair the input array to its corresponding output.

From your explanation, I understand that a -> 1, p -> 1, and n -> 0, and you have 100 samples in each category. So you just need to multiply the output array by 100. Try this:

```
deep_rank_model.fit([a, p, n], [y]*100,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            epochs=10,
            verbose = 1)
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize that it would not just take the label for every single one. I appreciate it